# How to use ubuntu dash as online search engine?

Tags: unity-dash, search, google, engine

I want to know if online google search engine searches can be done from within ubuntu dash. 
This is like a mini search engine within the ubuntu launcher.

If this is possible,how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Open your terminal and paste these lines one by one.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-answers
```

Then restart your computer for the changes to take effect.